# What is the path of the log file that can be used to scrape Google Cloud Armor logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datadog, google-cloud-armor

I want to setup an integration of Datadog using DD_AGENT. Have explored the Topics/Pub Sub route but still want to try out the Agent method.

It seems, the Agent will have a custom configuration, and needs to know the file path.

It also seems that Google Cloud Armor's logs cannot be viewed outside the console.

However, I was able to run this command:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=http_load_balancer AND jsonPayload.enforcedSecurityPolicy.name:(my security policy)"
```

What is the file path of such logs?

Comment: By path, do you mean file path? The logs are stored in a bucket name `_Default`. Accessing that bucket requires using APIs. You can also export the logs to your own bucket. I do not use the Datadog service, but they should support directly reading logs from Cloud Logging.